# Communication between browser of two application in different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I have one silverlight application hosted at www.abc.com

I have one web application hosted at www.xyz.com

I want to call the page of web application on button click of silverlight application and pass some parameters to it now silverlight application will show busy indicator until the transaction of the page of web application doesn't get completed. Now if the user has successfully done the transaction in the page or if he close the page of web application i want some parameters to pass to silverlight application so that it can know to stop the busy indicator and further process. I know there would be something in jquery or ajax which do such communication in cross domain but i am not getting it around.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use these alternatives:

**YQL** for ajax cross domain: [example with plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/)
**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**: [example 1](http://enable-cors.org/#how-iis7) [example  2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290053/setting-access-control-allow-origin-in-asp-net-mvc-simplest-possible-method) [example  3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765725/adding-headers-in-asp-net-mvc-3)
**implementation of jsonp in asp.net mvc**: [example](http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/07/cross-domain-jsonp-using-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery/)

Comment: Thank You andres it's very helpful examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSONP for cross domain ajax communication.

Example using jQuery :

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/