# Setting Header in ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I am trying to insert an header in my controller according with the parameter `sub`, but with no success. I have tried these two lines, here's the code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sub)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub))
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("sub", sub);
        Response.AddHeader("sub", sub);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Try this HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("sub",sub); OR Try this HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("sub",sub);

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765725/adding-headers-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Do you want this header to be accessible in all pages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may work for you..

```
public ActionResult Index(string sub)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sub))
    {
        HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("sub", sub);

    }
return View();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, but now I have another problem. My header is like an array, because previously I have setted the value "0" in it. How can I clear this header before setting it again?
Now the header is like: "xxxxx, 0" where 0 is the previous value.

Comment: Check if header exists first using Headers.AllKeys() and remove if it already exists..