# How to disable open ASP.NET MVC site in IFrame?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iframe

As I have already mentioned in topic, I have a MVC site and I need to disable loading it into IFrame.

I have created simple page for testing purpose and I try to load into two IFrames my site and Google.com. I can see that my site is loaded but Google isn't. It means that it's necessary to change something in my MVC site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://localhost:61831/" width="1200" height="800">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe src="http://google.com" width="1200" height="800">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

So what and where in MVC site I have to write to achieve that?

Comment: Is that what you looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958997/frame-buster-buster-buster-code-needed

Comment: @FelipeMiosso Not exactly, but still thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple and quick Solution is to add following in Global.asax -

```
protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
}
```

Then give a try with iframe. Pages will not open in iframes. HTH.

Comment: This is what I need, but there is one little mistake here: should be `Application_PreSendRequestHeaders` instead of `Application_PreSendRequestContent`.

Comment: I edited the answer. If my answer helped you, please mark it down as helped answer.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to use [`X-Frame-Options`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking#X-Frame-Options) HTTP header attribute to avoid ASP.NET MVC application be opened in IFrame.

There are several different way to insert this attribute to HTTP header:

1.[Configure IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21258452/2274652) to add this attribute to all HTTP responses

2.Set this attribute in every necessary action method of every controller

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
            return View();
        }
    }
```

3.Create C# attribute in a way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765923/2274652) and apply it to action methods and controllers

```
    [HttpHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
        }
    }
```

4.Set this attribute in `Global.asax` file

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.AppendHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also add an entry in web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  ...
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure IIS to always append the `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` header in it's responses.

- From IIS Management Console, select your application.
- In the main panel, double click Http Response Headers.
- Click Add from the upper right pane.
- Set the name to `X-Frame-Options` and the value to `SAMEORIGIN` then
  click OK.

This should prevent your site from being loaded into an iframe on a different host, *without using any javascript or any extra code*.

See [developper.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) for the header documentation and [technet.microsoft.com](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for IIS' configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As DrewMan suggested, you want to use X-Frame-Options header.

I would suggest you to download Nuget Package [NWebsec](http://nwebsec.codeplex.com) and there's [MVC specific package](http://nwebsec.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NWebsec.Mvc&referringTitle=Home). Also check out the [configuration](http://nwebsec.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configuration&referringTitle=NWebsec.Mvc) part.